# How can I return a randomly selected word from the dict file?

Tags: ruby

The dict txt file is located at: /usr/share/dict/words
I need to access the words on that list and randomly *puts* a word that contains between 4-9 letters for the user.

Comment: and what have you tried so far??

Comment: How is the file organized?  Is each word on a separate line, or are words separated by a space, etc.? Also, is this a one-time event or something that will be done many times? I noticed the green checkmark flashing on and off. There's no hurry to select an answer.  Wait a while, say a few hours, to see what you get.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I'm trying different answers to determine which is the best for my code.
The file I'm extracting the words from is a list of words each in their own line.

Comment: @Surya, I executed the command I checked below. Only thing I edited was .sample(input) to get a list of randomly selected words from the dict file based on the number of requests the user "input" into the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the words file contains one word per line:

```
puts File.read('/usr/share/dict/words').lines.select {|l| (4..9).cover?(l.strip.size)}.sample.strip
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pick = words.select { |w| w.size > 3 && w.size < 10 }.sample
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
file_contents = File.read("/usr/share/dict/words")
words = file_contents.split("\n")
puts words[rand(0..words.size-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient is to use `Random`:

```
rng = Random.new
words = File.readlines("/usr/share/dict/words")
words.select!{ |e| s = e.size; s >= 4 && s <= 9 }
pick = words[rng(words.size)]
```

You can also use `#shuffle` but this generates a new list so is certainly heavy:

```
words = File.readlines("/usr/share/dict/words")
words.select!{ |e| s = e.size; s >= 4 && s <= 9 }
pick = words.shuffle.first
```

If words are not separated by newlines, use `split`:

```
words = File.read("/usr/share/dict/words").split
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pick = ar.sample until pick.to_s.size.between?(4, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to randomly select a large number of words in a given size range, here is a method built for speed.

**Code**

```
def random_word(fname, size_range, window)
  f = File.open(fname, 'r')
  fsize = f.size
  loop do
    f.seek(rand(fsize)) # Random start byte, likely within a word
    next if f.eof?
    f.readline # Go next word
    window.times do
      break if f.eof
      w = f.readline.strip
      if size_range.cover? w.size
        f.close
        return w
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
words =
'Now
is
the
time
for 
all
Rubyists
to
do
some
coding'

FNAME = 'dict'
File.write(FNAME,words)

random_word(FNAME, (4..6), 3) #=> "some"
random_word(FNAME, (4..6), 3) #=> "time"
random_word(FNAME, (4..6), 3) #=> "some"

random_word(FNAME, (2..3), 5) #=> "the"
random_word(FNAME, (2..3), 5) #=> "for"
random_word(FNAME, (2..3), 5) #=> "is"

random_word(FNAME, (6..8), 3) #=> "Rubyists"
random_word(FNAME, (6..8), 3) #=> "coding"
random_word(FNAME, (6..8), 3) #=> "coding"
```

**Explanation**

There are two situation to consider.

- A very large number of random words in a given length range must be generated at one time.  Here it would make sense to construct an array with qualifying words and then just select offsets at random.  If the dictionary did not change over times, these arrays could be written to file, on for each size range of interest.
- Only a modest number of random words are to be generated at a time, or the desired size range frequently changed. In these cases, reading all the words in the dictionary into an array before selecting one (meeting the length requirement) at random would be highly inefficient. It is this latter situation that I have addressed.

The algorithm is very simple:

- Generate a random by offset within the dictionary file.
- Move the file pointer to that byte, which likely will be in the middle of a word.
- Read the rest of that line (unless already at the end of the file).
- Read up to a specified number of words (or until the end of the file is reached), searching for one within the specified size range.
- If a word is found, it is returned, else the file pointer is moved to a new random offset and the process is repeated.

The reason for searching for at most a given number of words from a given random file pointer offset (before randomly moving the file pointer) is to maintain randomness, but is probably not very important.  If this parameter were effectively +infinity, it would search to from the random location to the end of the file, which would slightly bias the selection of words closer to the end of the file.

This method does have a flaw: in several dictionaries it is biased against the selection of the word "aardvark".

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = File.readlines(filename)
sample_word = dictionary.sample.chomp
until sample_word.length.between?(5, 12)
  sample_word = dictionary.sample.chomp
end
puts sample_word
```

`chomp` also removes carriage return characters (that is it will remove `\n`, `\r`, and `\r\n`).